# Can you turn weather off in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The arrival of Minecraft Beta 1.5 brought weather conditions. However, it can at times be inconvenient when you're trying to screenshot something and show it off (as it reduces lighting and obstructs your view slightly). Is there anyway to turn weather off?

Alternatively, is there a way to speed up the duration of weather or "skip" it?

[image: Eww, bad for screenshots.]

Comment: Isn't that a screenshot notch uploaded to show that it wasn't working properly yet?

Comment: I found it on the Minecraft Wiki page for weather.

Comment: Any reason you can't just wait? Weather doesn't last forever.

Comment: I ended up waiting to get some screenshots but again, it's a little inconvenient. It'd be nice if there was a mod or some other way to disable weather.

Comment: Sometimes the weather lasts several days. I was going to ask a similar question, but about turning the weathers noise levels down, the rain is a bit too loud imo.

Comment: Your accepted answer is wrong and I have a screenshot to prove it.

Comment: Updated to fit current versions.  I don't want to use a bounty to wait for answers, as I can answer them myself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To toggle off weather type in `/gamerule doWeatherCycle false`

If you simply want to enable a particular weather cycle for a near infinite amount of time, you can use the command `/weather type time`, for example if you want to have clear weather for a year, you could use `/weather clear 9999999999`.

Minecraft Java Edition allows suffixing with a unit, `d` and `s` to indicate in-game `days` and `seconds` respectively. The maximum allowed value for this duration is `(2-2^-33)*2^127` or `340282346638528859811704183484516925440` so you could make the weather *essentially* permanent with:

```
/weather clear 340282346638528859811704183484516925440d
```

but a lower number is probably fine.

In Bedrock Edition, the number has a maximum value of `1000000` and you cannot use any unit suffixes.

- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/weather
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html

Answer (score 12):

This might be a little late, but.. I always use the command /time set 14000 (it's a default command). This command makes it completely dark, so you can use a bed. Most of the time the rain/snow is over when it's morning.

Answer (score 5):

With [**zombe's modpack**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/mod-packs/1272345-zombes-modpack-v9-0-2-upd-02-dec-15), you can control weather. ;)

If there is bad weather happening at night, a bed should help.

Answer (score 5):

if you just want to turn it off, you just need to type in one of the following commands:

```
/weather clear
/toggledownfall
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're not averse to a little cheating, the mod [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-100-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-nov-29-saves-enchantments/) has recently added the ability to toggle weather.

Answer (score 3):

There is no setting to turn this off, the only way to skip weather is as a side effect of sleeping through the night.

Of course if it's not night, or you don't have a bed, then you are stuck..

I wish Notch would add this option in, or at least allow for you to turn down the AMOUNT of rain, since I don't mind the fact that it happens, just the constant lag that it brings.

Comment: Switching your graphics to Fast should reduce the lag due to rain, since that turns off the splash particles and the splash noise. Less particle rendering + fewer sounds playing (should)= faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can install Optifine, then you can disable it in the settings.(Works in 1.8.1)

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted; this is a perfectly valid answer, the only downside (or upside) is that you can't turn it back on at will.

Answer (score 1):

To turn of rain, Type `/toggledownfall` while op'ed, if on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Turning particle effects down to a minimum will reduce the amount of weather effects shown in game.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was set the *gamerule* doDaylightCycle to false `/gamerule DoDaylightCycle false`  This allowed me to use a *daylight_detector* and hook it up to a sticky piston with a redstone block on the end. [image]

When it starts to rain the daylight_detector will lessen in power and emit less in redstone strength and be unable to power the sticky piston.  The sticky piston will deactivate pulling the redstone block with it, triggering the command `/toggledownfall`  [image]
.The daylight_detector will sense the change in lighting and reactivate the sticky piston so it can once again clear up the weather.

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting your game and then returning, it might help!

Comment: Nope, weather is saved.