# Remove rain in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you turn weather off in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/can-you-turn-weather-off-in-minecraft)

God I hate when it rains in Minecraft...

Is there a server command to stop/remove rain? Can you make your singleplayer world "rain-free"?

Or is it just plain not removable?