# How do I turn the weather cycle off all the time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the command to completely disable the weather in minecraft? I currently use /weather cycle 1000000 but it only works for a couple minutes. After that it resumes raining. I need the command to ensure it is permanently disabled for this world until I use a different command to make it resume. Thank you!

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/can-you-turn-weather-off-in-minecraft

Duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Use the command:

```
/weather clear 1000000
```

It sets the weather to clear for 1 Million seconds, which is 277.77 Hours. Not a permanent solution, but I think it's as close as you can get without adding mods. The command will accept any number between 1 and 1 Million if you wanted to turn it off for less than 11 days of continuous play.

Comment: He already uses /weather cycle 1000000. What's the difference between cycle and clear, and why does cycle only last for a couple minutes?

Comment: He uses /weather cycle. I can find no reference to such a command even existing, and have no idea what it would do if it does exist. I'm suggesting /weather clear, which sets the weather to clear for a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up a command block with the command `/weather clear` and hook it up to a redstone clock. Like this:
[image]

Comment: Putting the thing under a sunlight detector in a sunlit place would be more efficient, less redstone updates and command executions.